# ThreeTenABP in an Eclipse Maven project

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I use Eclipse with Andmore for my Android project (no intention to switch to Android Studio).

I have converted the project to a Maven project, and originally added ThreeTenBP as a Maven dependency with no problems. However, I then switched to ThreeTenABP and tried to add it as a Maven dependency. I see something got downloaded, but Eclipse keeps complaining about a missing dependency.

When I examine `~/.m2`, I see that a source JAR got downloaded for ThreeTenABP, but there is no binary JAR.

I use Gradle (on the command line) to build my project, and I see there is a file named `threetenabp-1.2.1.aar` in my Gradle cache, which I am not seeing in `~.m2`. (So yes, I can build my project, but I’d like to get rid of that pesky error in Eclipse.)

How can I get Maven to recognize ThreeTenABP (or any AAR for that matter)?

Comment: I don't use Maven, but [the Android Maven Plugin is supposed to handle AARs](https://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/aar.html).